# How to use Helvetica with Euler Math in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, context-lmtx

I want to typeset my ConTeXt document in Helvetica 11pt with Euler Math for mathematics.

The following seems to work

```
\setupbodyfont[heros,11pt]
```

but I am not sure how to deal with Euler fonts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define a typescript:

```tex
\starttypescript[euler-heros]
    \definetypeface[euler-heros] [ss] [sans] [heros]     [default]
    \definetypeface[euler-heros] [mm] [math] [eulernova] [default]
\stoptypescript

\setupbodyfont[euler-heros, ss, 11pt]

\startTEXpage[offset=1ex]
    Hello world! $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$
\stopTEXpage
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I get an error with your code: `Math error: parameter \Umathsup_shift_drop\textstyle is not set` (ConTeXt Process Management 1.04)

Comment: I reinstalled ConTeXt and it worked finally thanks again

Comment: It might be better to use `euleroverpagella` instead of `eulernova`. That way things like primes `$f'(x)$` and differentials `$\dd x$` work better. One might need to do `\usetypescriptfile[euler]` or so, as well, then.